# What is a contextual event in ADF?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I am learning Oracle's ADF and want to have a deeper understanding of contextual events.I am familiar with JSF and this abstraction is not there in vanilla JSF.So what is a contextual event and how can we as application developers take advantage of this feature of ADF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple terms contextual event is a way to communicate between two independent taskflows that are on the same page. Since the taskflows are independent they don't and shouldn't be aware or depend on specific other taskflows being in the same page. The contextual event mechanism allows them to keep their independence while still co-operating and passing events/data in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Quote:

> Contextual events have two parts:
>
> -A publisher (or producer), such as a button that raises a named event, with or without a custom payload
>
> -A handler (or consumer) that listens for a specifically named event or a wildcard event, to process that event
>
> The Contextual Events feature leverages the Oracle ADF binding layer,
>   passing event notifications and payloads to registered event handlers
>   in a bounded task flow or a parent view. Payloads are passed as
>   arguments to the method that processes events on the handler. The
>   payload content is customizable. By default, the payload for a
>   contextual event is a JavaServer Faces, an Oracle ADF Faces, or an
>   Oracle ADF binding event object.
>
> A view containing regions defines a task flow binding in the
>   executables section of its page definition file. The binding
>   hierarchically connects all binding containers that are initialized at
>   a given time for a current browser page. The event notification is
>   published to event mappings defined in an initialized binding
>   container. Events are passed to the local binding container first and
>   then published to parent and sibling containers.
>
> Events are first handled by event mappings that specify the event and
>   the producer name in their configuration. Event maps that contain only
>   the event name but specify a wildcard character (an asterisk) for the
>   producer name are notified last. You can suppress wildcard event
>   handling through a configuration change in the page definition file or
>   the adf-config.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

### Vanila JSF has Events (Action and ValueChange) and Event Listeners, Custom Components and Custom Event Listeners.  ADF Contextual events are  custom events supported by Oracle ADF.

Thanks
Peddi